# How can I improve my query efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a newbie at `MySQL`.

I am trying to make statistics using a `DATE` data.

[image]

**What I want to see the output is**

[image]

**My Query is**

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT count(user_id)
     FROM MYTABLE
     WHERE cr_dt > '2018-04' AND cr_dt < '2018-05'
    ) AS April,
    (SELECT count(user_id)
     FROM MYTABLE
     WHERE cr_dt > '2018-03' AND cr_dt < '2018-04'
    ) AS March,
    (SELECT count(user_id)
     FROM MYTABLE
     WHERE cr_dt > '2018-02' AND cr_dt < '2018-03'
    ) AS Febrary
FROM MYTABLE;
```

**AND MY OUTPUT IS**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(cr_dt > '2018-04' AND cr_dt < '2018-05') as April,
       SUM(cr_dt > '2018-03' AND cr_dt < '2018-04') as March,
       SUM(cr_dt > '2018-02' AND cr_dt < '2018-03') as February
FROM MYTABLE;
```

This assumes that `user_id` is never `NULL`.  You can take this into account:

```
SELECT SUM(cr_dt > '2018-04' AND cr_dt < '2018-05') as April,
       SUM(cr_dt > '2018-03' AND cr_dt < '2018-04') as March,
       SUM(cr_dt > '2018-02' AND cr_dt < '2018-03') as February
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

I would not use partial dates for this purpose.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT SUM(cr_dt >= '2018-04-01' AND cr_dt < '2018-05-01') as April,
       SUM(cr_dt >= '2018-03-01' AND cr_dt < '2018-04-01') as March,
       SUM(cr_dt >= '2018-02-01' AND cr_dt < '2018-03-01') as February
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL;
```